# conditional binary operator expected

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have code below in a .sh file. But it says `conditional binary operator expected` in the first line. How can I solve this error?

```
if [[ -f "${OUTPUT_BASE_PATH}/metrics.json" && ! -v again ]]; then
    echo "${OUTPUT_BASE_PATH}/metrics.json exists ... . Not running Training ";
else 
    echo "${OUTPUT_BASE_PATH}/metrics.json does not exist ... . TRAINING ";
    allennlp train -s $OUTPUT_BASE_PATH --include-package influence_info --force $CONFIG_FILE
fi
```

Comment: I suspect you have an older version of bash, that doesn't support the `-v` test (it was added in version 4.2). See ["Testing to see if an env variable is set in bash"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520356/testing-to-see-if-an-env-variable-is-set-in-bash) for other methods.

Comment: Can you run ` bash --version` and report to us what it says?